# Duplicate keys in a REST connector query in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I would like to ask if you know how could I duplicate parameters in a loopback REST connector query.
I have the following code:

```
details: {
    'template': {
      'method': 'GET',
      'debug': true,
      'url': 'https://www.example.com/data',
      'timeout': 10000,
      'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'
      },
      'query': {
        q: 'PHOTOS'
        q: 'DETAILS',
        id: '{id}'
      },
      'options': {
        'useQuerystring': true
      },
      'responsePath': '$'
    },
    'functions': {
      'searchData': [
        'token',
        'id'
      ]
    }
  }
```

The problem for that it is that it seems that loopback override the value of the parameter q by the last one, because I get only information for the last parameter.

Any idea how to solve it?

Thank you in avance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to pass them as an array:

```
  'query': {
    q: ['PHOTOS', 'DETAILS'],
    id: '{id}'
  },
```

Note that the `options` key, is [passed](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/REST-connector.html#configure-options-for-request)  to [request](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) and here's the documentation for `useQuerystring`:

> - `useQuerystring` - If true, use `querystring` to stringify and parse   querystrings, otherwise use `qs` (default: `false`).  Set this option
>     to   `true` if you need arrays to be serialized as `foo=bar&foo=baz`
>     instead of the   default `foo[0]=bar&foo[1]=baz`.

So if you remove it you'll end with something like `?q[0]=PHOTOS&q[1]=DETAILS`.

You can also another option there:

> - `qsStringifyOptions` - object containing options to pass to the [qs.stringify](https://github.com/hapijs/qs#stringifying) method.
>     Alternatively pass options to the 
>     [querystring.stringify](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.12.0/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options)
>     method using this format `{sep:';', eq:':', options:{}}`. For example,
>     to change the way arrays are converted to query strings using the `qs`
>     module pass the `arrayFormat` option with one of
>     `indices|brackets|repeat`

So you can actually end up with the same thing adding this:

```
  "options": {
    "qsStringifyOptions": {
      "arrayFormat": "repeat"
    }
  }
```

And if you want to have just the brackets(something like this `?q[]=PHOTOS&q[]=DETAILS`) you can specify `brackets` option:

```
  "options": {
    "qsStringifyOptions": {
      "arrayFormat": "brackets"
    }
  }
```